# using tabbedPanels in a formTable

Tags: xpages-extlib

has anyone got an example of using tabbedPanel in a formTable ?

my form has alot of fields, I'm new to Xpages so just looking for a best practice.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example of the opposite - a tabbedPanel, each with a formTable inside with validation, and it works well when there are a lot of fields.  Keep in mind that if you use the SSJS validation, whenever you click any tab, the current tab's validation will be triggered.

You can try a dojo tabContainer, with formTables inside, too, where if you switch tabs, no validation will be triggered.  You may get js errors, if you set the focus to a field which is in a different tab.  I'm not using a dojo tabContainer, because this project is for IE7 and I find it's very slow for this browser.